# How to get a list of all services available on cluster?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

Trying to use kubernetes-client and it works fine if I want to get a list of PODs. But how do I get a list of services, i.e.:

```
kubectl get services
```

I could not find any appropriate method in kubernetes-client:

```
const Client = require('kubernetes-client').Client;
const Config = require('kubernetes-client/backends/request').config;

const client = new K8sClient({ config: Config.fromKubeconfig(), version: '1.13' });

const pods = await client.api.v1.namespaces('xxxxx').pods.get({ qs: { labelSelector: 'application=test' } });
console.log('Pods: ', JSON.stringify(pods));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [godaddy/kubernetes-client](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/blob/master/docs/1.13/Service.md) Libraries.

There seems to be:

[`api.v1.namespaces(namespace).services.get`](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/blob/master/docs/1.13/Service.md#apiv1namespacesnamespaceservicesget)

> list or watch objects of kind Service

Which looks the same as:

[`api.v1.namespaces(namespace).pods.get`](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-client/blob/master/docs/1.13/Pod.md#apiv1namespacesnamespacepodsget)

> list or watch objects of kind Pod